# Invalid parameter value detected while passing data to moodle service

Tags: moodle

When I try to pass values to the moodle service I am getting the following error.
    {"exception":"invalid_parameter_exception","errorcode":"invalidparameter","message":"Invalid parameter value detected"}

Please check the URL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skUoC.png)

Comment: We need more info. What service do you call and what data do you send

Answer (score 0):

Here some observations:

- First of all, moodlewsrestformat must be the string 'json' or 'xml', it seems that you put the username here.
- Sms_regnumber does not seem to be a valid parameter, try removing this.
- Finally the username parameter is missing (users[0][username]).